# Find all components of the tensors $T_{ij}=u_iv_j+v_iw_j$ and $S_{ijk}=u_iv_jw_k-v_iu_jw_k+v_iw_ju_k-w_iv_ju_k+w_iu_jv_k-u_iw_jv_k$.

Tags: vectors, tensors

Given three vectors, $\vec u=(u_1,u_2,u_3)$, $\vec v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ and $\vec w=(w_1,w_2,w_3)$. Find all components of the tensors $T_{ij}=u_iv_j+v_iw_j$ and $S_{ijk}=u_iv_jw_k-v_iu_jw_k+v_iw_ju_k-w_iv_ju_k+w_iu_jv_k-u_iw_jv_k$.

---

Does $T_{ij}=u_iv_j+v_iw_j$ is just the sum of $u_iv_j$ and $v_iw_j$ as we sum over $i$ and $j$? So in this case $u_iv_j=u_iv_i+u_iv_j+u_iv_k+u_jv_i+u_jv_j+u_jv_k+u_kv_i+u_kv_j+u_kv_k$, similarly for $v_iw_j$? And analogously for $S_{ijk}$?

Comment: 1) $T_{ij} = T_{ji}$ so you only need to compute $T_{ij}$ for $i\geq j$. This reduces the $9$ components down to $6$. 2) If there are not repeated indices there is nothing to sum over so $T_{ij}$ is simply just $T_{ij}$.

Comment: you have $S_{123}=\det[\vec{u},\vec{v},\vec{w}]$